# Group object has name key value

Tags: python

I'm trying to group object to 1 object.

```
  ...rows = []
for alert in AlertConfiguration.objects().all():
    rows.append({
        alert.alarm_name : {
            alert.severity: alert.value,
        }
    })`
response = make_response(jsonify(rows), HTTPStatus.OK)
return response...
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sulaP.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw5Hf.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not clear.
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, please *Do Not* post your code as an image, post is as a text instead. [Here is why you should not post your code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15366635)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the images you provided, you could iterate over the items and merge the different values and assign it as value for a key in a new dict.
Here is the code.

```py
# Python 3.5+
structure = [
    {
        "system_load": {
            "Critical": 84
        }
    },
    {
        "system_load": {
            "Info": 80
        }
    },
    {
        "system_load": {
            "Warning": 85
        }
    }
]

result = dict()

for item in structure:
    for key, val in item.items():
        old_value = result.get(key, dict())
        result[key] = {**old_value, **val}
print(result)
```